# Overriding adminhtml of Community module

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, overrides

I am trying to rewrite a block for a module in the community code pool. The Module that I am trying to rewrite is TBT_Enhancedgrid. The directory structure is

```
app/code/community/TBT
└── Enhancedgrid
    ├── Block
    │   ├── Catalog
    │   │   ├── Product
    │   │   │   ├── Grid
    │   │   │   │   └── Columns.php
    │   │   │   └── Grid.php
    │   │   └── Product.php
    │   ├── System
    │   │   └── Html.php
    │   └── Widget
    │       ├── Grid
    │       │   ├── Column
    │       │   │   ├── Filter
    │       │   │   │   ├── Category.php
    │       │   │   │   └── Image.php
    │       │   │   └── Renderer
    │       │   │       ├── Action.php
    │       │   │       ├── Category.php
    │       │   │       └── Image.php
    │       │   └── Column.php
    │       └── Loyalty.php
    ├── controllers

app/code/local/Company/TBT/
└── EnhancedGrid
    ├── Block
    │   └── Widget
    │       └── Grid
    │           ├── Column
    │           │   └── Renderer
    │           │       └── Image.php
    │           └── Column.php
    └── etc
        └── config.xml
```

I am trying to re-write Column.php from the community module. The contents of the config file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config>
 <modules>
     <Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid>
         <version>1.3.2.1</version>
     </Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid>
 </modules>
 <global>
     <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
             <rewrite>
<widget_grid_column>Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column</widget_grid_column>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

The contents of the app/etc/module/Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <TBT_Enhancedgrid/>
        </depends>
    </Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid>
</modules>
```

✔

The Column.php file in local pool is

```
class Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column extends TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column
{ 
       /* with contents*/
}
```

But the function defined in Image.php in local code pool is not being over-ridden. I did read the other related posting before posting this question, but I still can't figure out what am I doing wrong. Any help would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In magento, a module should  **have two level folders** structure ***[ModuleNameSpace]>[ModuleName]***

You have created **three levels folder** structure **Company>TBT>Enhancedgrid**

That seem to be wrong at magento.

SO  you should change it to

***`Company>TBTEnhancedgrid`***  from ***`Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid`***

### Now folder structure should be:

```
app/code/local/Company/
└── TBTEnhancedGrid
    ├── Block
    │   └── Widget
    │       └── Grid
    │           ├── Column
    │           │   └── Renderer
    │           │       └── Image.php
    │           └── Column.php
    └── etc
        └── config.xml
```

**As the  module structure**  change that you need to change `Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid` to `Company_TBTEnhancedgrid` at all file at your module.

Also your must change `Company_TBT_Enhancedgrid.xml` to 
`Company_TBTEnhancedgrid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_TBTEnhancedgrid>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <TBT_Enhancedgrid/>
        </depends>
    </Company_TBTEnhancedgrid>
</modules>
```

Also , in magento rewrite a class not mean rewrite all class recursively  under that rewrite class.

Suppose, you have rewrite the class `TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column` not means rewrite `TBT_Enhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Image`

```
<global>
     <blocks>
         <enhancedgrid>
             <rewrite>
<widget_grid_column_renderer_image>Company_TBTEnhancedgrid_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Image</widget_grid_column_renderer_image>
            </rewrite>
        </enhancedgrid>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Assume that enhancedgrid is block  type of module **TBT_Enhancedgrid**